# Photo hosting service accepting donations for download?

Tags: copyright, web, selling, photo-galleries

I am a board member for a local little league in charge of marketing and communications. I run all the social media, take photos of games at the parks, etc., to help build our following for upcoming seasons.

All these photos I have been taking are on my own time. I use a small watermark with the league's logo on the bottom right of all the photos when I share them online.

Realizing that this is a lot of work and people enjoy the photos from the kid's games, I want to take these photos as my own business and help the league even more. While I would still post some photos in our social media campaigns, my thought is that the larger game galleries I would host elsewhere.

I am looking for a service where I can host image galleries with watermarks etc., but instead of charging people to buy them, I want to allow them to donate an amount of their choice to download the photo. Even considering a free option where they don't have to donate, we ask that they credit back to the league or something along those lines.

My goal here is not to profit for myself through this but earn some possible donations for our league as it's a 501C3 for images that parents or families where they choose to donate to "unlock / download" the photos at perhaps a higher resolution, smaller watermark, etc.

Many of the services I have seen are all purchase based.

Do you have any recommendations on a platform that allows donations or non-fixed purchases where they can enter an amount?

Comment: Questions seeking specific product or service recommendations, where the answer is likely to be either entirely personal or short-lived as a result of changing markets, are off topic here. Please rephrase your question to describe the problem you're trying to solve or what you do not understand that prevents you from determining the answer yourself.